# How to limit Google Chrome from consuming all available memory while uploading large files to mega?

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks

When uploading relatively large file or a few big files Google Chrome consumes all available memory on my pc. There is no such problem in Firefox. How to limit Google Chrome from consuming all available memory while uploading large files to mega? What is the reason for such a strange behavior? Is it considered to be a memory leak?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Chrome is a multi-process browser.This was intentionally designed to make web apps run faster in Chrome. This feature makes the browser zippier and more stable even with multiple open tabs.disabling multiple processes can free up some CPU resources.To handle each web process Chrome has three settings

1. process-per-tab
2. process-per-site
3. single-process

Create a shortcut for Chrome. Open the Properties tab. Edit the Target field as shown in the picture by appending –single-process to the path.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google know about this bug. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175233

Answer (score 2):

On linux distro the memory available to the chrome process can be limited by using ulimit, 1024MB in the bellow example.

Try a script with the following (e.g chrome-limited.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
ulimit -Sv 10240000 #amount of memory available in bytes 
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```